# Possible alignments of two lists using Python

Tags: python, string, list, alignment

I have two strings in two different lists `A = [dog bit dog null]` and `B = [hund bet hund]`.
I would like to find all possible allignments from list B to list A such as :

```
  C =  [(hund = dog, bet = bit, hund = dog),
        (hund = dog, bet = bit, hund = bit),
        (hund = dog, bet = bit, hund = null),
        (hund = dog, bet = dog, hund = dog),
        (hund = dog, bet = dog, hund = bit),
        etc.. ]
```

I think there are 64 different allignments between these two strings.
I am working on the IBM model1 for word translastion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 64 possibilities, you could use `itertools.product`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> A = "dog bit dog null".split()
>>> B = "hund bet hund".split()
>>> product(A, repeat=3)
<itertools.product object at 0x1148fd500>
>>> len(list(product(A, repeat=3)))
64
>>> list(product(A, repeat=3))[:5]
[('dog', 'dog', 'dog'), ('dog', 'dog', 'bit'), ('dog', 'dog', 'dog'), ('dog', 'dog', 'null'), ('dog', 'bit', 'dog')]
```

but note that this is going to generate a fair number of duplicates, given that you have `dog` twice in `A`:

```
>>> len(set(product(A, repeat=3)))
27
```

You could even get the associated triplets of pairs if you wanted:

```
>>> trips = [zip(B, p) for p in product(A, repeat=len(B))]
>>> trips[:5]
[[('hund', 'dog'), ('bet', 'dog'), ('hund', 'dog')], [('hund', 'dog'), ('bet', 'dog'), ('hund', 'bit')], [('hund', 'dog'), ('bet', 'dog'), ('hund', 'dog')], [('hund', 'dog'), ('bet', 'dog'), ('hund', 'null')], [('hund', 'dog'), ('bet', 'bit'), ('hund', 'dog')]]
```

Comment: It is important that I keep the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
[(i,j) for i in a for j in b]
```

You can't have that structure in a list, you'd need a dictionary, I am using a tuple here to associate the values.

Comment: This results : [(u'hund', u'dog'), (u'hund', u'bit'), (u'hund', u'dog'), (u'hund', u'null'), (u'bet', u'dog'), (u'bet', u'bit'), (u'bet', u'dog'), (u'bet', u'null'), (u'hund', u'dog'), (u'hund', u'bit'), (u'hund', u'dog'), (u'hund', u'null')]
But I want to have a tuple for each possible alignment from one list to another.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: No, I want to have hung = dog, bet = dog , hung = hund in one tuple